# "Wish" in the credits of Code Geass and Steins;Gate?

Tags: anime-production, code-geass, steins-gate

I've recently started watching anime. I've watched Code Geass R1 and R2 and now I've just started Steins;Gate. I was surprised to see that in both series' ending credits the word "Wish" appears between the Japanese characters in a similar font, since it's the only one or one of the few words in English.

This is a screenshot from Code Geass R2's credits showing what I mean

[image: end credits from Code Geass R2]

Does it have any special meaning?

Comment: It's probably this company: http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wish_%28%E3%82%A2%E3%83%8B%E3%83%A1%E5%88%B6%E4%BD%9C%E4%BC%9A%E7%A4%BE%29

Comment: Thanks everybody for the great answers.About Steins;Gate, I think the section says: 動画協力
Wish
アニタス神户
太観アニメ

Comment: It should be the same company. 動画協力 is probably Finish Animation Cooperation? The other 2 are [Anitus Kōbe](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/company.php?id=9342) and [Taikan Anime](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/company.php?id=5963).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure about *Steins;Gate*, however, from the screenshot above, **Wish** refers to [an animation company](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/company.php?id=4062).

In the screenshot above, the company is credited for Finish Animation (仕上 *shiage*), and the people on the list are [[伊藤 良樹]{Itou Yoshiki}](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/people.php?id=11320), [[加藤 里恵]{Katou Rie}](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/people.php?id=28036), [[熊田 真子]{Kumada Masako}](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/people.php?id=79248), [[加藤 明美]{Katou Akemi}](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/people.php?id=75061), [[斎藤 知津江]{Saitou Chizue}](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/people.php?id=18914), [[江草　大樹]{Egusa Daiki}](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/people.php?id=57678), [[角野 江美]{Kadono Emi}](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/people.php?id=55063), [[三上　幸恵]{Mikami Yukie}](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/people.php?id=84577).

**Wish** is not a particularly big animation company. From the list on ANN, they are mostly in charge of Finish Animation, In-Between Animation, 2nd Key Animation, Digital Paint, etc.  So far, they have only produced a single anime title *Elite Jack!! (OAV)* in 2014.

Comment: on Anime News Network's [Steins;Gate page](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=11770), under you can see Wish having been listed under Finish Animation, In-Between Animation and 2nd Key Animation, on the [Code Geass Page](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=6704) it is listed under In-Between Animation, Digital Paint and In-Between Check. as you have listed in your last paragraph

Answer (score 4):

The section of the credits you're looking at there is 仕上 *shiage* "finishing", which is the task of finishing the coloring of a scene. [Wish](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/company.php?id=4062) is a studio that does subcontracting for this kind of work.

Their name is in English because why not. See also: J.C.Staff, Production I.G., Sunrise, Studio Feel, ufotable, and so forth.

The other eight names in that section are the names of people (not studios); I suspect they're employees for Wish. (At least one of them, [Katou Rie](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/people.php?id=28036), is, it seems.)